# Can spin structures and Arf invariants be defined in terms of local quantities, like Chern classes and Chern numbers?

Tags: spin-geometry, index-theory, chern-classes, dirac-operator

I'm interested in if it's possible to represent a spin structure and the Arf invariant associated to it in terms of some sort of local fields.

For example, the first Chern class of a complex line bundle on a manifold is some element of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, which on a 2d manifold equivalent to specifying an integer, the Chern number $c_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

All of these concepts have local interpretations after putting a $U(1)$ connection on the bundle, in terms of the connection 1-form $A_\mu dx^\mu$ and the curvature 2-form field on the manifold, $F = (\partial_\mu A_\nu) dx^\mu \wedge \ dx^\nu$. In this case, the Chern class can be thought of as $\frac{1}{2\pi}F \in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \subset H^2_\text{(de Rham)}(X,\mathbb{R})$. And the Chern number is given as the integral of this local quantity, $c_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_X F$.

I was curious whether or not there was an analogous interpretation of a spin structure and the Arf invariant.

From my (pedestrian, physics) point of view (as explained in section 2.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05550)), a spin structure is an element $\rho \in H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ which specifies periodic or antiperiodic boundary conditions on each nontrivial cycle, and the Arf invariant is $ind_{\text{mod 2}}(D_\rho)$, where $D_\rho$ is the Dirac operator associated to the spin structure and $ind_{\text{mod 2}}(D_\rho) $ is the mod 2 index of the operator.

My question could also be phrased as whether this mod 2 index of a Dirac operator is some integral of some local quantity that is "canonically" associated to the spin structure.

Comment: The index of the Dirac operator is given by the $\hat{A}$ genus and hence is independent of the spin structure. However, the Arf invariant is not the same for all spin structures, so I am a bit confused by your claim that "the Arf invariant is $(-1)^{ind(D_{\rho})}$".

Comment: I should have said Arf = $ind(D_\rho) \text{ (mod 2)}$, which is how it's defined in [the paper I linked](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05550) in section 2.2. For a 2-torus, I believe the index depends on the spin structure. The Dirac operator is $\partial_x + i \partial_y$, acting on functions with either periodic or antiperiodic boundary conditions on opposite sides of the fundamental domain (each of the 2x2 choices of boundary conditions is a spin structure). This operator on the torus can only have a zero mode for constant functions, which only happens for the doubly periodic case.

Comment: @Joe that notation is a little misleading to me. The "mod 2 index" is different from "the value of the index modulo 2", so I personally wouldn't denote it by $\mathit{ind}(D_\rho) \pmod 2$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit my post. I'm still familiarizing myself with these concepts

Comment: @ArunDebray: What is the mod 2 index?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese suppose $T$ is a real skew-adjoint elliptic operator. Then its index in the usual sense vanishes, but $\mathrm{dim}\mathrm{Ker}(T)\bmod 2$ is still a useful invariant, and it's called the mod 2 index. For example, if $S$ is a closed spin 2-manifold, the index of the spin Dirac operator on $S$ vanishes, but the mod 2 index is the Arf invariant of $S$; this identification is due to [Johnson](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-22/2/365/802380?redirectedFrom=PDF). (continued...)

Comment: Another perspective on the mod 2 index that I like uses $K$-theory. If $M$ is a spin $4k$-manifold, the (usual) index of its spin Dirac operator is the image of $1\in\mathit{KO}^0(M)$ under the pushforward map $p_!\colon \mathit{KO}^0(M)\to\mathit{KO}^{-4k}(\mathrm{pt})\cong\mathbb Z$. But in dimensions $8k+1$ and $8k+2$, the $\mathit{KO}$-group of a point that we obtain is $\mathbb Z/2$, and so performing the same construction yields the mod 2 index.